# Fire event only once based on current mousemove position

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i fire an event only once in per condition / situation shown in the snippet below?

In my example, if mouse position's x position value is between 25 - 50,
and if the y position value is 0 - 25, it will fire an event.
but the event fires repeatedly if you see the console.

How do i log the console (or more events if add them later) only once per condition? And if the mouse leaves the 'conditions', and return later on, the console.log will fire again?

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos){
  var xCord = getCurrentPos.pageX;
  var yCord = getCurrentPos.pageY;
  xPercent = xCord / $( document ).width() * 100;
  yPercent = yCord / $( document ).height() * 100;


if ((xPercent > 0 && xPercent < 25) && (yPercent >= 0 && yPercent < 25)){
console.log('1'); /* how to fire only once?*/
/* more events here later */
} else if ((xPercent >= 25 && xPercent <= 50) && (yPercent > 0 && yPercent < 25)) {


console.log('2'); /* how to fire only once?*/
/* more events here later */

}else if ((xPercent >= 50 && xPercent <= 75) && (yPercent > 0 && yPercent < 25)) {
        console.log('3');/* how to fire only once?*/
/* more events here later */
    } 

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `only once per event` should be `once per condition` i think this way it will be clearer.. you can have a variable set it to true and inside the condition set it to false.. add it to the condition. but if you have many condition i dont think this is an option

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m5m8on83/) one and two will be console once but this is using variable

Comment: hmm it doesnt seem to work on mousemove? only saw the console.log when i refreshed with the mouse position in the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! You just have to avoid going to set some unique value for each condition and check it again when entering... and reset it when not.

```js
var currentArea = false;
    $(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos){
      var xCord = getCurrentPos.pageX;
      var yCord = getCurrentPos.pageY;
      xPercent = xCord / $( document ).width() * 100;
      yPercent = yCord / $( document ).height() * 100;

      if ((xPercent > 0 && xPercent < 25) && (yPercent <= 0 && yPercent < 25)){
        if(currentArea!="Area1"){
          console.log('1');
          currentArea = "Area1";
        }
      } else if ((xPercent >= 25 && xPercent <= 50) && (yPercent > 0 && yPercent < 25)) {
        if(currentArea!="Area2"){
          console.log('2');
          currentArea = "Area2";
          //do this
        }
      }else if ((xPercent >= 50 && xPercent <= 75) && (yPercent > 0 && yPercent < 25)) {
        if(currentArea!="Area3"){
          console.log('3');
          currentArea = "Area3";
          //do this
        }
      }else{
        console.log('outside')
        currentArea=false
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable like `entered` which you defined outside the `mousemove` event.

```js
var entered = false;

$(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos){
    var xCord = getCurrentPos.pageX;
    var yCord = getCurrentPos.pageY;
    var xPercent = xCord / $( document ).width() * 100;
    var yPercent = yCord / $( document ).height() * 100;

    if(entered) {
        return; // skip rest of code if already entered once
    }

    if ((xPercent > 0 && xPercent < 25) && (yPercent <= 0 && yPercent < 25)){
        entered = true;
        console.log('1');
        /* how to fire only once?*/
        /* more events here later */
    } else if ((xPercent >= 25 && xPercent <= 50) && (yPercent > 0 && yPercent < 25)) {

        entered = true;
        console.log('2');
        /* how to fire only once?*/
        /* more events here later */

    }else if ((xPercent >= 50 && xPercent <= 75) && (yPercent > 0 && yPercent < 25)) {
        entered = true;
        console.log('3');
        /* how to fire only once?*/
        /* more events here later */
    } 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe you also just want to have a look at this jQuery mouseenter example at the bottom of the page: https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: ah but when my mouse leaves the 'conditions' and returns, it doesnt fire 'once' again?

Comment: @wsgg of course not cause the title said: "Fire event only **once** based on mouse position" but also cause I thought that might be a problem I linked the jQuery mouseenter and if you follow that example, with my answer you should be able to solve everything

Comment: perhaps i should have phrased it better. my bad. im actually looking to have it again once the conditions are met again.

Comment: @wsgg nice title change now :) I have no more time though

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to log the events you have already fired. That way you can use any number of events. Once an event is fired, it will be logged to the array, and next time we check whether we have already run that, if so, we ignore it.

```
        <script>
        var logged = [];
        $(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos) {
            var xCord = getCurrentPos.pageX;
            var yCord = getCurrentPos.pageY;
            xPercent = xCord / $(document).width() * 100;
            yPercent = yCord / $(document).height() * 100;

            if ((xPercent > 0 && xPercent < 25) && (yPercent <= 0 && yPercent < 25) && ($.inArray(1, logged) == -1)) {
                logged.push(1);
                console.log('1'); /* how to fire only once?*/
                /* more events here later */
            } else if ((xPercent >= 25 && xPercent <= 50) && (yPercent > 0 && yPercent < 25) && ($.inArray(2, logged) == -1)) {
                logged.push(2);
                console.log('2'); /* how to fire only once?*/
                /* more events here later */

            } else if ((xPercent >= 50 && xPercent <= 75) && (yPercent > 0 && yPercent < 25) && ($.inArray(3, logged) == -1)) {
                logged.push(3);
                console.log('3');/* how to fire only once?*/
                /* more events here later */
            }
        });
    </script>
```